# Intercept Keyboard Input and Return Custom Value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to create a background service with WPF and .net that intercepts the keyboard input and if some conditions are met, return a custom value. I wish to make it work with softwares that have text input fields such as word/google/notepad/etc....

[the concept would be that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdbea.png)

I got the Low-level keyboard input working fine thanks to this tutorial: 
http://www.dylansweb.com/2014/10/low-level-global-keyboard-hook-sink-in-c-net/

I also got the conditions and calculations for the new input working.

I, now, want to know if it is possible to "intercept" the keyboard input instead of just reading it with a listener and change the return value. 
The goal would be that if I press Key.E, it doesn't display E immediately but go through my service first, then display the result accordingly (ex: Press Key.E for t < 1sec = "e"; t >=1 = "Custom input with fancy calculations").

I also wanted to know if I could change the "Accessibility -> Filter Keys" settings through the app. Indeed, if I press Key.E more than 1sec, I don't want to have "e" spammed before the output arrives.

I wanted to know if it was possible to do with a WPF app and if so, what's the best way to do it. I'm fairly new at coding with the .net framework and c# in general.

Any help/advices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Alexandre

Comment: What you look for requries understanding the difference between KeyDown, KeyHold and KeyRelease. Modern GUI usually goes out of it's way to give you events for that on every GUI Element. But you have to re-invent those the hard way for your case.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My understanding of how windows manage the key input is that it sends the write "e" event to the software on KeyDown, then loop between KeyDown and KeyPressed until the KeyUp event is called. I was wondering if there were a way to delay the write "e" event to the KeyUp function when the WPF app is in background. (windows is not loaded/active)